# Pull data from SqlServer Database into jQuery Full Calendar using codeigniter3

Tags: json, ajax, fullcalendar, codeigniter-3, fullcalendar-3

I am facing same issue from so many days... Previously I worked with same calendar with PHP, but my project is in Codeigniter, so it is not fitted into my project... So now I am working with Codeigniter..

**Controller Code**

```
class Calendar extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        Parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Calendar_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('Calendar_view');
    }

    public function load()
    {

        $query = $this->Calendar_model->load_events();

        $data_events = array();

        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $data_events[] = array(
                "title" => $row->title,
                "start" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($row->start_event)),
                "end"   => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($row->end_event))
            );
        }

        echo json_encode($data_events);
    }
}
```

**Model Code**

```
class Calendar_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        Parent::__construct();
    }

    public function load_events()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get("events");

        return $query;
    }
}
```

When I run the above with this url `http://localhost/calendar_sql_copy/index.php/Calendar/load`,

I got following data

```
[{"title":"Meeting2","start":"2019-09-30 00:00:00","end":"2019-09-30 00:00:00"},{"title":"Meeting2","start":"2019-02-08 00:00:00","end":"2019-03-08 00:00:00"}]
```

But when I try to pull same data into Fullcalendar in following way..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        editable:true,
            header:{
                left:'prev,next today',
                center:'title',
                right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
        selectable:true,
        selectHelper:true,
        // events:[
        //   {
        //   "title":"Meeting2",
        //   "start":"2019-09-30 00:00:00",
        //   "end":"2019-09-30 00:00:00"
        //   }
        // ]
       events:'<?php echo site_url('Calendar/load'); ?>'
</script>
```

If I show same data in static way as

```
events:[
           {
              "title":"Meeting2",
              "start":"2019-09-30 00:00:00",
              "end":"2019-09-30 00:00:00"
            }
        ]
```

It pops up into calendar,

But when I try to render with URL like below,

```
events:'<?php echo site_url('Calendar/load'); ?>'
```

Here is the data from the browser Network tool: https://intouchsystems-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/gurubaran_k_icsoft_co_in/EZE8m-w3Pn1HoktYxL2yHPQBKcuosFXP1M3uT69bh9qn9Q?e=4%3a5RjKNu&at=9

It does not show even my Calendar....

Where I done mistake please tell me....

It is very important module in my project...

In my organization no WebDevelopers are there, and I am new to this Codeigniter...

Comment: In your HTML source code what does the site_url() show? I don't know fullcalendar but according to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed it will pass specific parameters in as well which relates to date periods. Have a look in your browser Console > Networking tab to see if any data is being requested. You may find it gives you more info or an error.

Comment: From site_url(), I am trying to accessing data from Calendar/load (means controller/method), I didn't get and data or errors in Console, even my Calendar is not showing...Thanks for your reply

Comment: Have you looked in your browser Console > networking tab? Hit F12 in Chrome.

Comment: Ya, I did n't get anything... It's empty only

Comment: Check what is inside `events` with `console.log("<?php echo site_url('Calendar/load'); ?>")`

Comment: Just to be clear, you have to open the Network tab **before** you load your page. Unlike the console, it will not show requests which happened before you opened the Developer Tools. And in some browsers (like IE) you also have to actively press a button to switch on the network logging. So if your Network tab is completely blank, it suggests you didn't open it up before loading your page. Open it, then refresh your page. You should see a request for your main page, followed by requests for the fullCalendar files, and then lastly your events URL.

Comment: I changed events as you suggested,events: console.log("<?php echo site_url('Calendar/load'); ?>"), but no output in console.. and in Network tab it is giving status code 200....

Comment: http://localhost/calendar_sql_copy/index.php/Calendar/load, it gives me status code 200  and I got output,     but for "<?php echo site_url('Calendar/load'); ?>" it redirects  to the http://localhost/calendar_sql_copy/index.php/Calendar, it gives 500 error code and calendar is not loading

Comment: No, not `events: console.log("<?php echo site_url('Calendar/load'); ?>")` ...good grief. That will just break your code. You need to get a grip of some JavaScript basics, I think. Look... leave it as `events:'<?php echo site_url('Calendar/load'); ?>'` . Then load your page. Then open the View Source feature of your browser (in Chrome, you can press Ctrl+U, or it's in the menu). Scroll through the generated HTML until you come to the `events: ...` entry. Exactly what does it say? Does it show as `events: 'http://localhost/calendar_sql_copy/index.php/Calendar/load'`? Or something else?

Comment: It shows as               events: '                                                                                  It does not showing path? Where it raises problem?

Comment: <h4>An uncaught Exception was encountered</h4>

<p>Type: Error</p>
<p>Message: Call to undefined function site_url()</p>
<p>Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\calendar_sql_copy\application\views\Calendar_view.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 25</p>

Comment: I fixed half issue by using $autoload['helper'] = array('url');    Now I got Calendar... But not loading events

Comment: Now when I used Ctrl+U, then I got like this     events: 'http://localhost/calendar_sql_copy/index.php/Calendar/load'

Comment: Good. Ok, next step is to examine the Network tab correctly (as I described earlier) and see what is returned that fullCalendar visits that URL.

Comment: Ya it gives me Name : Calendar ; Status : 200 ; Type : document

Comment: Click on the request to Calendar. Look in the "Response" section. Does it contain your event JSON? Paste the exact contents of that response into your question, then we can examine it.

Comment: Sorry sir, I didn't get what you said? "Click on the request to Calendar. Look in the "Response" section",

Comment: In the Network tab. Where it shows the request going to "Calendar", that's clickable. Click it. It will open another section showing details of that request. One section within that is called "Response". This will show you what information was returned by the server. You would get a view something like this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/imgs/response.svg

Comment: P.S. I recommend using Chrome's developer tools to debug your code, if you aren't already. There is guidance here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Comment: I didn't get json data sir, I got events path only, like                                            events: 'http://localhost/calendar_sql_copy/index.php/Calendar/load'

Comment: By following that URL I got following json data:  [{"id":"4","title":"Meeting2","start":"2019-07-31 00:00:00.000","end":"2019-07-31 00:00:00.000"},{"id":"10003","title":"Meeting2","start":"2019-02-08 00:00:00.000","end":"2019-03-08 00:00:00.000"}]

Comment: I done some datetime conversions too...Then the json is like follows   [{"id":"4","title":"Meeting2","start":"2019-07-31 00:00:00","end":"2019-07-31 00:00:00"},{"id":"10003","title":"Meeting2","start":"2019-02-08 00:00:00","end":"2019-03-08 00:00:00"}]

Comment: Hello Sir, any wrong in my json data? Why it is not loading into Calendar?

Comment: No there's nothing wrong with your JSON. Here's a demo loading your 2nd sample JSON (from your last comment) from a demo URL: http://jsfiddle.net/b0dLjksn/ . If you load the calendar and change the month to July you start to see the events. And if you examine the Network tab you can see the JSON being downloaded, it will look like this: https://imgur.com/a/lK2vn8M

Comment: If that isn't happening in your case, then you need to check why. Either a) you're not using the right URL, or b) the server is not returning the right data. Run the Network tool in your own page and look for the call to "Calendar/load". It will give you the clues. I've shown you how to do it, but you don't seem to have done that yet. Or if you have, you haven't shown me the results. You **must** learn how to use the Network tool if you want to be able to successfully code which uses AJAX. It is a vital debugging tool. Take the time to study how to use it.

Comment: Hello Sir I followed https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network, and found my json data as follows... [{"id":"30008","title":"testing on Aug-12,2019","start":"2019-08-13 00:00:00","end":"2019-08-14 00:00:00"},{"id":"30009","title":"testing on Aug-12","start":"2019-08-15 00:00:00","end":"2019-08-16 00:00:00"},{"id":"30010","title":"Updated on Aug-12 Mad Birthday","start":"2019-08-14 00:00:00","end":"2019-08-14 17:00:00"},{"id":"40003","title":"as","start":"2019-09-12 00:00:00","end":"2019-09-13 00:00:00"}]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199789/discussion-on-question-by-sowmya-gayam-pull-data-from-sqlserver-database-into-jq).

Comment: That JSON is completely fine. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/94y6bpe0/ (you can see that I added your sample JSON [here](http://myjson.com/qdd4h) and linked to it in JSFIddle). From the information you've provided it's impossible to understand what your problem could be.

Comment: Dear Sir, In Network tab I got my json as follows...
[{"id":"4","title":"Meeting2","start":"2019-07-31 00:00:00","end":"2019-07-31 00:00:00"},{"id":"10003","title":"Meeting2","start":"2019-02-08 00:00:00","end":"2019-03-08 00:00:00"}]

Comment: Previously when I done same task with PHP, I got successful output... and my JSON as following way
0: {id: "4", title: "Meeting2", start: "2019-07-31 00:00:00", end: "2019-07-31 00:00:00"}
1: {id: "10003", title: "Meeting2", start: "2019-02-08 00:00:00", end: "2019-03-08 00:00:00"}
2: {id: "10006", title: "hello", start: "2019-08-01 12:40:31", end: "2019-08-01 12:40:31"}
Is any problem with my json? But in both PHP Code and Codeigniter3 code, after I loop through database data I used predefined method "json_encode($var_name);"

Comment: Dear Sir, In Network tab I got my json as follows... [{"id":"4","title":"Meeting2","start":"2019-07-31 00:00:00","end":"2019-07-31 00:00:00"},{"id":"10003","title":"Meeting2","start":"2019-02-08 00:00:00","end":"2019-03-08 00:00:00"}]

Comment: Previously when I done same task with PHP, I got successful output... and my JSON as following way 0: {id: "4", title: "Meeting2", start: "2019-07-31 00:00:00", end: "2019-07-31 00:00:00"} 1: {id: "10003", title: "Meeting2", start: "2019-02-08 00:00:00", end: "2019-03-08 00:00:00"} 2: {id: "10006", title: "hello", start: "2019-08-01 12:40:31", end: "2019-08-01 12:40:31"} Is any problem with my json? But in both PHP Code and Codeigniter3 code, after I loop through database data I used predefined method "json_encode($var_name);"

Comment: Dear Sir I got the data in Network tool, but it is not pulling into my Calendar...Can you give me any solution to solve this issue....Thank you so much sir...You taught me very useful things... and please help me to solve this issue

Comment: It would be great to have some screenshots of the various relevant parts of the network tool. Like I said, it's unclear what the issue is because the JSON itself seems to be fine

Comment: P.S. I forgot to ask...do you see any errors in the browser's Console, also?

Comment: No sir, I did n't get any errors in Browser's Console

Comment: It's completely baffling then. As I said, screenshots needed, so we can understand **exactly** what you are seeing on your page and in your Network tools.

Comment: How can I share my screen shots to you sir?

Comment: upload them to [imgur](https://imgur.com/) and then add links to them in your question

Comment: Dear sir weather I have to share my code files, or only output? Thank You Sir...

Comment: You've shown us the code already. What we want to see is the evidence about how the page is loading, what Ajax calls are happening, and what the output of the Ajax calls are... mainly the one calling the calendar/load URL

Comment: Dear sir you can see my output screenshots in the following link.....https://intouchsystems-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/gurubaran_k_icsoft_co_in/EZE8m-w3Pn1HoktYxL2yHPQBKcuosFXP1M3uT69bh9qn9Q?e=4%3a5RjKNu&at=9

Comment: Ok I think the reason for the problem is this: `<!-- Calendar.php --> <!-- Calendar_model.php -->` in your Response. Your response must contain **JSON only** and **nothing else**. No other text, no whitespace at the start and end...nothing except the JSON. If you include other data like this then fullCalendar cannot parse the JSON correctly. It cannot tell which part is JSON and which is comments. I'm surprised you don't have a console error about it actually. But please ensure that the server is not outputting extra data in the response. I am hopeful that will fix the problem.

Comment: Yes Sir... Thank You so much... I got my data on Calendar....

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided both in the question and the comments, the the reason for the problem is this:

`<!-- Calendar.php --> <!-- Calendar_model.php -->`

in your AJAX Response. Your response must contain **JSON only** and **nothing else**. No other text, no whitespace at the start and end...nothing except the JSON. If you include other data like this then jQuery (and thus fullCalendar) cannot parse the JSON correctly.

Please ensure that the server is not outputting extra data in the response. That will fix the problem.